# Trust https://localhost:3000/ of MEAN stack in Chrome & Mac

Tags: ssl, openssl, localhost, ssl-certificate, keychain

I use Chrome in macOS Sierra 10.12.3. I guess I have already set up `ssl` for `localhost` long time ago. Now, both `http://localhost/` and `https://localhost/` in Chrome return the list of folders under `localhost`. I have created a nodejs app. So after typing `npm start` in a command line to run the server, we could open `http://localhost:3000/#/home` as frond-end in Chrome.

Now, for some reason, I need to make `https://localhost:3000/#/home` work in Chrome. At the moment, it gives `This site can't be reached; localhost unexpectedly closed the connection` error.

Does anyone know how to amend this? Should I set up something in mac or in the code of my app?

**Edit 1:** I have found this page: [SSL/HTTPS server with Node.js and Express.js](http://kyrcha.info/2014/10/14/sslhttps-server-nodejs-expressjs/). So I generated the files and modified the node code. Now loading `https://localhost:3000/#/posts/editor/` displays the page, but I want to remove the annoying `Not Secure` warning.

[image]

As the above screenshot shows, I was able to view its certificate (though there is an error `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`). I copied the certificate to the desktop and dragged it to `login` of the `Keychain Access` tool and modified its setting to `Always Trust`. I restarted Chrome, reloaded the page, but the `Not Secure` warning is still there.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: *"I guess I have already set up ssl for localhost..."* - Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually lots of threads about this issue, which are quite confusing. I write the way that works for me.

1. I have finally followed this page to generate the files http://blog.mgechev.com/2014/02/19/create-https-tls-ssl-application-with-express-nodejs/. Note that I set `localhost` as `Common Name` (not sure if it's really mandatory).
2. In `www` of my MEAN project

   ```
   var fs = require("fs");
   var config = {
       key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
       cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
   };
   var server = https.createServer(config, app).listen(3000);
   ```
3. In Chrome, I open `https://localhost:3000/#/new`, then I go to the `Security` tab of `Dev Tools` to view its certificate. Then drag the certificate to the desktop.
4. Double-click the certificate on the desktop, which opens `Keychain Access`. Make sure the certificate is in `login` (not necessarily `system`). If it's not, then drag the certificate in `login`.
5. Change everything to `Always Trust`
6. (maybe restart `Chrome`), after `npm start` the application, enjoy surfing `https://localhost/#/new` with Green Secure Light.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you setup a Certificate Authority? Perhaps you only setup `https` in your code but forgot to setup a local Certificate Authority for your app to validate a certificate with. If this is the case please reference: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/create-your-own-ssl-ca-with-the-os-x-keychain/

Comment: This next error you are facing is likely caused by the fact this is a self-signed certificate that does not come from a root level Certificate Authority. Essentially you should just need to add an exception for this in chrome. Please reference: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/add-permanent-ssl-certificate-exception-chrome-andrey-batyrenko

Comment: I don't see `On the "Certificate Store" screen of the import`... please see my update...