# Default chromecast receiver app will not load

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am trying to run the default receiver application provided on https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver_basic#google_caf_receiver_sdk_google-caf-receiver-sdk. When I attempt to load the receiver in my Chrome 65 it throws errors in the console:
`r_new.html:4 GET file://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/caf_receiver/v3/cast_receiver_framework.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

`r_new.html:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: cast is not defined at r_new.html:10 (anonymous) @ r_new.html:10`

I am aware of the protocol `//` agnostic URL. If I change it to `https://`, it loads the first script and then fails on the rest. This may be a security or developer issue, but I am not sure how to correct it.

**UPDATE**

After using node http-server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) and the following instructions https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058453/3997521 to successfully generate a cert for my localhost server on Chrome 65 OSX: `http-server -S -C MyCompanyLocalhost.cer -K MyCompanyLocalhost.pvk -o`

Notes: Don't forget to install MyCompanyCA.cer as well to match and restart chrome and it will take the cert.

I still get the following error even when the page loads properly with the index.html file:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTouchInputSupport' of undefined
    at Object.cast.receiver.platform.setTouchInputSupport (cast_receiver_framework.js:81)
    at Af (cast_receiver_framework.js:116)
    at T.start (cast_receiver_framework.js:483)
    at localhost/:10`

**UPDATE 2: results for windows same properly provisioned cert**

`receiver.html:63 Starting receiver application
cast_receiver.js:89  [  0.000s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Opening net websocket
cast_receiver.js:89  [  0.003s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Version: 2.0.0.0061
cast_receiver.js:89  [  0.005s] [cast.receiver.MediaManager] Using default Player
receiver.html:68 Starting receiver manager
cast_receiver.js:115 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTouchInputSupport' of undefined
    at te (cast_receiver.js:115)
    at N.start (cast_receiver.js:97)
    at receiver.html:82`

**UPDATE 3: tried on a live server with a real provisioned cert Chrome 66 Windows**

`cast.receiver.platform.setTouchInputSupport @ cast_receiver_framework.js:81
Af @ cast_receiver_framework.js:116
T.start @ cast_receiver_framework.js:483
(anonymous) @ reciever.html:10`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't make a typo? Try using localhost.
If you do decide to use localhost, then you will need a server running.
When your server is running, copy this example:

localhost/myfiles/yourfile.yourcode

Comment: Server is running and I posted the results above. Any further ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this error, and in April this error popped up. It looks like google added some codes to check platform.
Ref to news [goole first change chromecast prevent amazon](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16509834)

This error would block castManager to start ws connection on localhost:8008
In real chromecast, it would be okay without this error.

Comment: If what you are saying is true, then does that mean the Chromecast receiver demo would still show as discoverable by any devices looking to cast?