# This site is not sure: Windows does not have enough information to verify the certificate

Tags: internet-explorer, localhost, ssl-certificate, microsoft-edge

I want to make a website run in localhost in Edge.

I guess previously (long time ago) I used [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44058453/702977) to generate the certificate.

I try to open `https://localhost:3000` in Edge, it gives an error `This site is not sure` and `This might mean that someone's trying to trick you or steal any information that you send to the server. You should close this site immediately.`

After double clicking on the certificate error, it shows that `Windows does not have enough information to verify the certificate.`

Then, I click on `Install Certificate` and install it in the local machine `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`. We can see that in the MMC.

But relaunching Edge with the same url still gets the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I just don't understand why IE/Edge/Microsoft made it so hard.

PS: in IE, it does not work either.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might because Microsoft Edge has network isolation by default for security reasons. You could enable loopback by running the following command from a cmd prompt as administrator for Build 10158 and newer, then restart Microsoft Edge:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```